# Get Metadata of the mp3 file in the assets folder programmatically in android

Tags: android, mp3, media-player

I need to get the metadata of an mp3 file which is in the assets folder of my project.
I need to get details like Authors, Genre , Year, Duration etc.
Is it possible in android to get such details ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this class MediaMetadataRetriever in android, but it is available from 11 and onwards.
Is there any other alternative.?